# prohibit access to pdf files via URL

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, apache-httpd, htaccess

Simply I am trying to prevent access to all pdf files on my server from being reached and downloaded using URL Eg https://domain.com/test.pdf .
What I succeed to do is : to prevent indexing them, but it still accessible via URL.

**What I've tried so far :**
in both files
*mywebsite.conf,
apache2.conf*

```
<Files  ~ "\.pdf$">
    Require all denied
</Files>

<Files  ~ "\.pdf$">
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
</Files>
```

I tried to block the directory as well but did not work.(with/without VirtualHost).

I changed **AllowOverride** to **All** in apache2.conf

I tried to block them using .htaccess

```
<FilesMatch ".*">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from All
</FilesMatch>
```

still accessible.
(Ubuntu 20.04)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I might wonder why you have files on a web server that you don't want others to access. Can't you simply remove them from the server?

Comment: "_prevent indexing them, but it still accessible via URL"_ - don't link the URL targets from any other place that can be indexed. Crawlers can't magically find your targets - they crawl other pages that reference them. Don't reference them and they won't be discoverable by machine. (That doesn't stop someone who knows the URL path from linking it from one of their own pages, of course.) You should also consider using a `robots.txt` to indicate to web crawlers that you would like them not to index (part of) your website.